# Trouble Initializing Class

Tags: swiftui, ios14

If I leave out the class initializer I get an error; if I add all five initializers I still get an error saying I didn't initial all the stored properties. All the initializers show the error 'Variable 'self.baseCur' used before being initialized.

```
struct BaseModel: Codable {
    var baseS: String
    var baseI: Int
    var baseSym: String
    var baseCunN: String
    var baseCurN: String
}

class TotalFormats: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var baseCur: BaseModel
       
    init() {
        self.baseCur.baseS = "USD"
        self.baseCur.baseI = 0
        self.baseCur.baseSym = "$"
        self.baseCur.baseCunN = "United States"
        self.baseCur.baseCurN = "Dollar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not created yet, only declared, that's why an error. You need to create it via constructor

```
class TotalFormats: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var baseCur: BaseModel
       
    init() {
        self.baseCur = BaseModel(baseS: "USD", baseI: 0, baseSym: "$", 
           baseCunN: "United States", baseCurN: "Dollar")
    }
}
```

or

```
class TotalFormats: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var baseCur = BaseModel(baseS: "USD", 
       baseI: 0, baseSym: "$", baseCunN: "United States", baseCurN: "Dollar")
       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi, can you point me to where constructors are discussed? I couldn't find anything on the subject even on swift.org